# Is it possible to install themes created for VS Code to WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, phpstorm, webstorm

Is it possible to install themes created for `Visual Studio Code` to IntelliJ products such `WebStorm` or `PhpStorm`? If yes, how?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to directly import VSCode color schemes into JetBrains IDEs.
But you can look for similar WebStorm/Phpstorm themes on the web. For example, you can try the theme with the UUID 57b63a1c849f3a1800dc1a1f from https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes or https://github.com/lenny1882/vscode-dark-plus-webstorm; I'd also suggest looking at [Material Theme UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui) plugin - it's a UI theme + a set of editor color schemes